# Micrometer stopped publishing metrics after migration to Spring Boot 3

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-cloudwatch, micrometer

Recently we migrated our application to Spring Boot 3, no configuration for micrometer was changed, but it stoped pushing metrics to AWS Cloudwatch.

During debugging I see that instead of **CloudWatchMeterRegistry** **SimpleMeterRegistry** is autowired.

Our integration:
Dependency for micrometer-cloudwatch:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-registry-cloudwatch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Dependency for spring-cloud-aws:

```
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Properties file:

> management.metrics.export.cloudwatch.batchSize=20
>
> management.metrics.export.cloudwatch.namespace=metrics

Not sure what is the root cause, and did not find anything in migration documentation related to metrics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spring-cloud-starter-aws is not mainatained by the Spring team anymore.
It is maintained by the community, see here: https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws

`spring-cloud-starter-aws:2.2.6.RELEASE` is neither supported nor compatible with Boot 3.x, you need to upgrade.

Comment: Yep, have found it on my own back in May. But thanks a lot anyway!